# MCMC autocorrelation convergence diagnostic

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, autocorrelation, convergence, metropolis-hastings

I use MCMC (Metropolis-Hastings) to sample posterior distributions of three parameters using a nonlinear least-squares objective function to calculate the likelihood of a parameter sets.

I want posteriors for about 500 different conditions, each time I calculate a posterior with MCMC.

Since it is hard to check all 500 runs by hand for convergence, I would like to have a simple rule based on autocorrelation which indicates for each run if the chain converged or not, checking all conditions individually would be very cumbersome.

Each chain has length 40000 (burn-in already removed) and I calculated autocorrelations for lags 1 to 10000.

I then calculated the autocorrelation time as the time constant for the autocorrelation series (the first lag when the autocorrelation drops below `1/exp(1)`).

I get autocorrelation times between 16 and about 7000.

I suppose that with an autocorrelation time of 16 I can be sure that the Markov chain converged, but is there maybe some "rule of thumb" which tells me, given a chain of length 40000, which autocorrelation time is still "acceptable"?

I searched and looked for instance [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4258/can-i-semi-automate-mcmc-convergence-diagnostics-to-set-the-burn-in-length), however, the approaches I found  require a visual investigation.

Comment: I believe what most people do (if the algorithms are fast enough and time is no issue) is to take the highest boundry, that is, judge the worst-behaving draw (in terms of autocorrelation) by visual inspection, multiply the resulting burn-in by 2, and apply that to all chains.

Comment: Does this mean I calculate the new burn-in time using the autocorrelation and then calculate my chains again? Time is an issue for me, so I would like to assess convergence from the chains that I have now...

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the standard tests for convergence?

The Geweke's convergence diagnostic works with a single chain and provides a z-score. There is also the Heidelberger and Welch's convergence diagnostic, which also works with a single chain and gives a p-value of the null hypothesis that the sampled values come from a stationary distribution. If you run multiple chains, there's Gelman and Rubin's convergence diagnostic. If you use R, all of these are implemented in the `coda` package.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I looked into Geweke's convergence diagnostic in `coda` and calculated the z-scores. Then I calculated p-values using `2*pnorm(-abs(z))`

Comment: I calculated the pvalues using Heidelberger and Welch as well and they differ quite substantially from the pvalues I calculated from the z-score from Geweke's diagnostic. Also, I see that if the autocorrelation time is very low (<100), the p-values are very high. I must still be missing something...